# need to update multiple columns of datatable concurrently

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a datatable(with record around 200000) which consist of columns ID and description like 
dtCustomer
customerID,customerDesc,AddressId,AddressDesc,employeeId,employeeDesc
initially this data table will contain value in id column only.
To assign description need to query each respective master datatable like customermastertable, addressmastertable, employeemastertable.

By iterating through each master table and assigning description its taking more than 1 minute. This is not acceptable. I need to optimize this process.

Can I use threading or task? Is there any possibility of arising atomicity even we are updating different columns in datatable. It thats possible could any one help me in this.

Comment: Can you show us the layout of the tables?

Comment: Are you talking about actual .NET `DataTable` objects or do you just mean a database table?  Is there a particular reason that you're not just doing a single query with multiple joins?

Comment: It is a datatable object. At the program startup it will assign all the data in memory to minimize database call i.e. datatable to be updated, and all the master table will be in memory in from of datatable